# What is the utility of updateString() method of resultset in java?

Tags: java

In what situation anyone would update resultset data (afterall we just need data from databse, if i want to update i will update my database and not resultset data)? And if i need to update underlying database then why not do it by using SQL query, what is point in getting data in result set then update it, then again update database using updaterow() method?

Comment: Simplicity, I think. Think about a program that needs to analyze billions of records (one at time) and edit some values with some math. It's a lot faster and easier (and readable too) to update each value while iterating, and calling `updateRow()` at the end of the loop instead of writing the query, binding all parameters and executing it.

Comment: You will only receive opinion. And this is easier to add some condition on the updates to do from the resultset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very nice feature. Normaly is the ResultSet not updatable. But you can create it as an updatable `ResultSet`. Look at this simple example:

```
Statement statement = conection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ITEMS");
while (rs.next()) {
    int count = rs.getInt("COUNT");
    if(count > 0) {
        rs.updateInt("COUNT", 0);
        rs.updateRow();
    }
}
```

So you don't have to write a SQL Query for update.